# "Evil" thinking vs. lashon hara

Tags: sources-mekorot, product-recommendation, speech-talking, bein-adam-lachavero, thought

If a person's explicit verbiage about someone else is benign on the surface, but has an unexpressed and somewhat nasty thinking behind it, is this considered lashon hara? Are there any guidelines or sources as to how to attenuate those unkind motives which will enhance one's attitude towards others and make one's speech more kindly?

Comment: It sounds like you are referring to something that actually is a category of Lashon Harah, generally known as Avak Lashon Hara (translated as Dust of Lashon Hara). See a couple examples [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Chofetz_Chaim%2C_Part_One%2C_The_Prohibition_Against_Lashon_Hara%2C_Principle_9%2C_Opening_Comments.1?vhe=Chofetz_Chaim&lang=bi) and [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Chofetz_Chaim%2C_Part_One%2C_The_Prohibition_Against_Lashon_Hara%2C_Principle_2.2.2?vhe=Chofetz_Chaim&lang=bi) in the Sefer Chafetz Chaim.

Comment: @Salmononius2 Yes, your second link includes what I have in mind. But perhaps even more stringent. Really what's in one's mind. And I might go so far as to say an negative thought, such as "What a jerk."

Comment: I dont thinking alone without saying anything is included. The basic idea of LH is not to harm someone and this is not done by thinking alone.

Comment: Can you clarify what sort of action/thought you are referring to? It sounds like you are equating thought and speech (i.e. the title of your question mentions thinking, while the body of your questions mentions 'communication'. Your comment mentions "what's in one's mind" as well as "say an negative thought" which is speech). Can you clarify what you're looiking for, since there is a huge gap between what one is simply thinking and an action that results from it.

Comment: I have removed most of the extra language from the post in an attempt to make the question clear. Feel free to roll back the edits if you don't like what I did. In general you want to omit any excess sentences and thoughts from the text of your question because it confuses readers and makes it more difficult to answer your question.

Comment: @BabySeal No problem. Thanks for your kind consideration. With regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rav Hutner says that the foundational *issur* of *lashon ha'ra* is judging unfavourable (*dan le'kaf chov*).

The *lashon ha'ra* is an expression of the negative evaluation that you have attributed to the person whom you have judged unfavourably.

So the basic *issur* of *lashon ha'ra* is to construe someone else as having negative value.

Comment: I really like that analysis (as it's what I think). Did he offer any teaching(s) to remedy it. Thanks.

Comment: @user663837 From a *mussar* perspective, the antidote is attention to *penimiyot* over *chitziniot*. That means that if your aim in life is to achieve concrete goals you are more likely to end up talking *lashon ha'ra* than if your aim in life is personal growth.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to Rav Hutner. An interesting irony in your comment: my penimiyot or the other's? Maybe you could link Rav Hutner's writings on lashon ha'ra in English if available.

Comment: @user663837 I have never seen this in English. No irony intended.

Comment: I would like to buy your sefer (it is yours, right?) Both because the sample on amzn looks great and I would like to recognize you endeavor. I actually own no printed books or sfrorim, doing much better reading on the computer with backlighting. If by chance you have a pdf or something comparable that you would consider sending me, I could pay you via paypal. Either way, thanks. Best regards,

Comment: @user663837 Thanks for the positive feedback. It's funny that you mention that because I was just wondering if I should do a e-version of the book, I guess you are saying yes. Will ping you when this is available, could be a while though with Purim and Pesach coming up. Thanks!!! Kol tuv.

Comment: Funny - I just bought the hard copy a minute ago. If you do produce an e-version I'm sure we'll be in touch. Wouldn't have wanted to wait a couple of months to get the full GRAPKE inspiration. BTW, really, how did you come up with a handle that's not even Frisian, but western Frisian no less. Best regards,

Comment: @user663837 I didn't come up with it. It was invented by the *bochur* sitting in front of me in afternoon *seder*.

Comment: I was curious: in that the Coriolis effect spins backwards down under, does Hebrew read linx tsu rekhts there?

Comment: @user663837 See https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%96%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A8_%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7_%D7%98%D7%95 ועם כל דא דיהך בארח מישר, דלא יסטי לימינא ולשמאלא, ואי לאו מיד אסתלק מניה ואתרחק מניה, ולא יכיל למרווח ליה כדבקדמיתא

Comment: Dear GRAPKE - you give me too much credit. Would you please translate for me. Thanks

Comment: @user663837 The Zohar says you must always continue on a straight path that is dictated by the balance of right and left. So regardless of whether the right is predominant or the left is predominant you have to continue on the same way.

Comment: You turned my joke into sound advice: balance.

Comment: Hi - In your sefer, on p.252 in the last paragraph, it says,"Totally relinquish the attitude of desiring money altogether." A strong set of double superlatives. Does that mean in general one should have no desire for money? I.e., pertinent to Pesach - live afilu min ha tamchui? Thanks and best regards,

Comment: @user663837 Reb Tzadok says that the reason Yitzchak was the wealthiest of the *avos* is that his *middah* was *gevurah* and therefore he was able to control unlimited wealth without the money having dominion over him. This seems to be the same idea as the Mahral's explanation of *lechem oni* being the bread of freedom, the *ani* is free because he is unadulterated by wealth.

Answer (score 1):

Judaism isn't as overtly focused over negative thoughts like some other religions are. The Christians follow a Rabbi who says that someone who murders in their heart or commits adultery in their heart is guilty of the actual thing. Judaism as a whole is not willing to take this stance. Thinking about murder is definitely different than murder itself, since one causes no harm outside the self and the other ends a life. But I believe Judaism still has a concept of the place you let your mind go will eventually be the place your mind spends most of its time. If you let yourself have unchecked fleeting thoughts of adultery, you will eventually have unchecked periodic thoughts of adultery, and then possibly frequent thoughts of adultery. This is not ideal and there is value in trying to prevent your mind from regularly going to such negative places unchecked.

For me, these kind of negative thoughts occur most often when I'm driving in LA. Someone cuts me off, or does something legitimately dangerous and I might have a momentary thought about that person that is terrible. So I apologize to God, in English. Because I know that the more often you let yourself "go there" guilt free, the more likely you will keep "going there."

Another common situation is when I have negative thoughts toward how someone dresses. So I take another moment to apologize to God for judging how a person is dressing, rather than doing the right thing and judging myself for how I looked at them and my emotional response to them. The only one responsible for where my eyes go is me, not someone else.

Comment: Really like the road-rage remark. Ironically something similar motivated my question. Actually it was pedestrian (me) v. driver rage. Not that I didn't need to ask the question a zillion times already. But this incident and my access to MY gave me the impetus. And with it the self-reflection of how often I react to even the slightest thing that doesn't go my way. But as far as thought go, there's machshava, dibbur, and maaseh (forgive my poor transliteration) and  it all starts with thoughts. Either they can be managed, but better if one is not so readily inclined.